# Symfony2 Custom Exception and Authentication token

Tags: php, security, exception, symfony, token

**[NOTE] too see final workaround, scroll down**

after 12 hours of headbanging and reading tons of materials I gave up and asking someone to help me how to solve the **"The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.)"** problem.

How I can pass the security context correctly to my custom handler?

I have following setup:

- Env: prod
- Debug: false

**security.yml**

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        path\to\SsoAccount: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        sso:
            id: sso_account_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        sso:
            pattern:    ^/
            logout:
                path:   sso_logout
                target: homepage
            anonymous: ~

    access_control: ~
```

**config.yml**

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    exception_controller: "acme.controller.exception_controller:showAction"
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        project_url: "%cfg_project_url%"
        sso_server:  "%cfg_sso_server%"
        sso_server_admin:  "%cfg_sso_server_admin%"
        google_drive_api_key:   "%cfg_google_drive_api_key%"
        oauth_client_id:        "%cfg_oauth_client_id%"
    form:
        resources:
            - "MainBundle:Form:fields.html.twig"

services:
    acme.controller.exception_controller:
        parent: twig.controller.exception
        class:  Acme\MainBundle\Controller\ExceptionController
        arguments: ["@security.context"]
        calls:
            - [ 'setContainer', ['@service_container']]
            - [ 'setSecurityContext', ['@security.context']]
```

**Acme/MainBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController as BaseExceptionController;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class ExceptionController extends BaseExceptionController
{
    protected $securityContext;
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function setSecurityContext(SecurityContext $context)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $context;
    }

    public function showAction(
        Request $request,
        FlattenException $exception,
        DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null,
        $format = 'html'
    ) {
        $this->exceptionClass = $exception->getClass();

        return parent::showAction($request, $exception, $logger, $format);
    }

    protected function findTemplate(Request $request, $format, $code, $debug)
    {
        /*********************/
        /** PROBLEM IS HERE **/
        //$user = $this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER');
        /** PROBLEM IS HERE **/
        /*********************/

        if (!$debug) {
            return 'MainBundle:Main:error404.html.twig';
        }

        return parent::findTemplate($request, $format, $code, $debug);
    }
}
```

**Acme/MainBundle/Resources/views/Main/error404.html.twig**

```
{% block body %}
    {{ render(controller('MainBundle:Main:error404')) }}
{% endblock %}
```

**Acme/MainBundle/Controller/MainController.php**

```
/**
 */
public function error404Action()
{
    /** ALWAYS return null **/
    $getUser = $this->getUser();
    /***********************/

    if (!empty($getUser)) {
        $account = $this->getUser()->getAccountInfo();
        $user    = $account->Account["0"]->user;

        return $this->render(
                    'MainBundle:Main:error404_loggedin.html.twig',
                        array(
                            'account' => $account,
                            'user'    => $user,
                        )
        );
    }

    return $this->render(
                'MainBundle:Main:error404_not_loggedin.html.twig',
                    array()
    );
}
```

The "not logged in" error 404 doesn't have any problem since no security added for it, but displaying different one for logged in members made me feel miserable, so please advice. Thanks!

---

*** Final Workaround ***

---

**Acme/MainBundle/Controller/MainController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/404", name="publicError404")
 */
public function publicError404Action()
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(404);

    $templateFile = 'MainBundle:Main:error404_not_loggedin.html.twig';
    $templateData = array();

    $getUser = $this->getUser();
    if (!empty($getUser)) {
        $templateFile = 'MainBundle:Main:error404_loggedin.html.twig';

        $account = $this->getUser()->getAccountInfo();
        $user    = $account->Account["0"]->user;

        $templateData['account'] = $account;
        $templateData['user']    = $user;
    }

    $templateData['token']     = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getId();
    $templateData['sso']       = $this->container->getParameter('sso_token');
    $templateData['timestamp'] = time(); //date(DATE_RFC822)

    return $this->render($templateFile, $templateData, $response);
}
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
services:
    acme.controller.exception_controller:
        class:  Acme\MainBundle\EventListener\NotFoundRouteListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
        arguments: [ @router, @service_container, @kernel ]
```

**Acme/MainBundle/EventListener/NotFoundRouteListener.php**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MainBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class NotFoundRouteListener
{
    protected $container;
    protected $router;
    protected $kernel;

    public function __construct(Router $router, ContainerInterface $container, Kernel $kernel)
    {
        $this->router    = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->kernel    = $kernel;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $isProduction = ($this->kernel->getEnvironment() == "prod") ? true : false;
        $isDebug      = ($this->kernel->isDebug() == true) ? : false;
        $routeName    = $this->container->get('request')->get('_route');

        /**
         * Display only if:
         *      - env = prod
         *      - debug = false
         *      - route = empty
         */
        if ($isProduction && !$isDebug && empty($routeName)) {
            $url = $this->router->generate('publicError404');
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
        }
    }
}
```

I will not paste the content of error404_not_loggedin.html.twig and error404_loggedin.html.twig since it's not needed for the question and solution.

Comment: Why do you have YAML in XML files?

Comment: They are .yml, sorry. Will fix that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security logic is executed after the routing logic (prior to 2.1, it was execute before). This means that a 404 error thrown by the router cannot use security, as there is no information about the security yet.

Nut you can also throw 404 errors in a controller, where security information is available. To make it available in any case, check if the security context is available and set up and if not, just render the not logged in templated

Comment: U/sing your suggestion I create a workaround (added in first comment). Thanks!